# Grothendieck group of finite cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, grothendieck-rings

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of isomorphic classes of all finite cyclic groups $[C_n]$, with $C_n \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Define relations on $\mathcal{C}$ as follows: if $A \leq B$ is an inclusion of finite cyclic groups, then
$$ [B] = [A] + [B/A]. $$
If I am not mistaken, we have that $(\mathcal{C},+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_0,\cdot)$.

My question is somewhat general, so I hope it makes enough sense: what are other interesting examples where we obtain "well-known" groups through this construction, with $\mathcal{C}$ replaced by some other set of groups ?

For instance, what happens when $\mathcal{C}$ consists of all finite abelian groups ? Or all groups ?

Comment: For the class of finite cyclic group or finite abelian groups, the universal invariant that is additive under extensions is the one mapping a group to its cardinal, valued in the multiplicative group $\mathbf{Q}_{>0}$ (so, the Grothendieck group is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}_{>0}$, which is free abelian of infinite countable rank). For the class of all groups it is clear that the Grothendieck group is trivial.

Comment: For the class of finitely generated abelian groups, the universal extension-additive invariant is given by the $\mathbf{Q}$-rank, and thus the Grothendieck group is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$.